# What was the first "all-civilian" animal spaceflight?

Tags: spaceflight-firsts, animals

As long as SpaceX is ([inaccurately](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55014/26446)) claiming the "first all-civilian spaceflight", **what was the first spaceflight with animals that were all "civilians"?**  That is, they had never been raised or trained at a military facility.

Monkeys Able and Baker were raised at the Naval Medical School in Pennsacola, and Ham the Chimp was trained at the Holloman Air Force Base, so they do not count.

Suborbital flights are fine, as long as they exceed the 100 km FAI line.  Be sure to consider Soviet flights.